# PHP ActiveRecord last_query not filling in?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

```
$remote_ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $today_date = $todaydate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $tomorrow_date = $tomorrowdate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $conditions['conditions'] = array('ipaddress = ? AND dateattempt > ? AND dateattempt < ?', $remote_ip, $today_date, $tomorrow_date);

        $attempts = self::all($conditions);
        //$attempts = self :: all(array('conditions' => array('ipaddress = ?',$_SERVER["REMOVE_ADDR"])));

/*          print_r($_SERVER); */
/*          print_r($today_date); */
/*          print_r($tomorrow_date); */

        echo self::connection()->last_query;
```

I have the following code above.  What happens is I'm trying to print out the query so I can see if I did the query correctly.  The query runs correctly but the command self::connection()->last_query prints the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE ipaddress = ? AND dateattempt > ? AND dateattempt < ?
```

The problem is it should be filling in the ? with the conditions but its not.  How do I get it to show me the results with the ?'s filled in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last_query` is the raw SQL. PHP ActiveRecord is using [PDO's prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) so you won't see the actual query.

What you should do is using a logger. The values will be shown there ([the code](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Connection.php#L295-L328)).

```
$log = Log::singleton('file', 'my.log'); //using PEAR Log
ActiveRecord\Config::instance()->set_logging(true);
ActiveRecord\Config::instance()->set_logger($log);
```

Example from: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/4/topics/1119-re-show-last-sql-query

Comment: I will give this a try and report back any questions I have.  Thanks!